# How to add a PHP Variable into HTML code

Tags: php, html

So I am trying to make a multiplication table and have run into this issue :

```
<?php
$table = '';
if ($_POST) {
    $table .= '<table border="1">';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['qty_line']; $i++) {
        $table .= '<tr>';
        for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['qty_column']; $j++) {
            $val = $i * $j;
           $table .= '<td width="50"> VARIABLE GOES HERE </td>';
        }
        $table .= '</tr>';
    }
    $table .= '</table>';
}
?>
```

Sorry if this is a very simple question but I can't find a solution after searching. Basically i want to insert the $val variable into where it says "VARIABLE GOES HERE" on that specific table data cell. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
$table .= '<td width="50">' . $val . '</td>';
```

See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you. It works, I was doing that before although i wasn't closing the html and thus not concatenating it properly. Stupid mistake on my part..